# Starting stream from another node?

Tags: elixir

I create a file stream on a node, I am concerned about the file access, as what if I start the stream from another node?

Like, on node A, I create the stream without starting it:

```
stream= File.stream!(path)
Agent.start(fn -> %{"stream" => stream}  end, name: {:global, :my_stream} )
```

then, on node B, I start the stream:

```
stream= Agent.get( {:global, :my_stream}, fn %{"stream" => stream } -> stream end )
Task.start_link(Stream, :run, [stream])
```

Would the stream look up the file on node A as expected? or would it look for it at node B ?(considering node B is where the stream is started), as it will fail if did so because the file is actually exists on node A.

Shall I associate the node at which the file is stored? how would I do so? do I have to?

Any idea?

Comment: What is `path` here?  If it is file it has to be equally visible from both nodes.  This won't necessarily be true on a remote node.

Comment: `path` is the file (including the path), I have each node on a separate server, so, do you think my approach is not safe? or at least, not guaranteed to work?

Comment: From my experience using `File.stream` on network connected nodes is that you need a local copy of that file on each  erlang-VM with a `path` name  adapted for each that file-system/OS - else it won't work. A `File` is not an URL.

Answer (score 0):

`File.stream!` returns a `File.Stream` struct which contains 4 fields: `path`, `modes`, `raw`, and `line_or_bytes`. The file is actually only opened when the stream is executed, using e.g. `Stream.run/1` or any `Enum` function. When you pass that struct to another node using `Agent`, only this 4 field struct is passed and if you call `Stream.run` on it in that other node, that node will attempt to open the file pointed to by `path` which will fail if a file doesn't exist on that node's filesystem. So, the answer to your question is that the operation will fail unless a file exists at the same path.

File handles in Elixir on the other hand are PIDs which internally store a reference to a file that is opened. They can be created e.g. using `File.open!/1`. If you pass the PID returned by this call to another node, and then do an operation on it, e.g. `IO.read` (not `File.read`) on that node, it'll succeed as the operations are sent as messages to the PID. The file operations are transparently transferred over the connection if the File handle's PID is from another node). So, if you want to access a file like this, you can use `File.open!` and then `IO.read` from it from another node.